# tmux: are my other terminals still running?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, unix, ubuntu, tmux

I have started using a certain technique for launching my web code since I switched server setups.

I type

```
tmux
sudo startserverrails
```

Ctrl+B then D

Then to reboot I type

```
tmux
sudo killall ruby
sudo startserverrails
```

Ctrl+B then D

My questions are: when I kill the ruby, does that end the session that I started with tmux? And if not, are those sessions gonna "build up" and cause issues (such as slow my machine either by processor or memory)? If so, how do I close all current tmux sessions that aren't named?

This question may be altogether incorrect in the sense that I misunderstand `tmux` completely. If so, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tmux list-sessions` to list active tmux sessions. If you don't explicitly close them, they may linger on. Use `tmux attach` to attach to an existing session. If you have more than one active session, you will be asked which one you want to resume.

`man tmux` is your friend.

Comment: Thanks, after listing, `tmux kill-session -t 3` killed the old extra session